# bash is eating characters during while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

Why is bash eating some characters during the following while-loop?

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_DIR=$1
OUTPUT_DIR=$2

rm -rf  "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
mkdir -p "${OUTPUT_DIR}"

cd "${INPUT_DIR}" && find . -type f -name '*.m4a' | while IFS= read -r original
do
    TMPFILE="$(mktemp --dry-run)"
    IN_FILE="${INPUT_DIR}/${original}"
    OUT_FILE="${OUTPUT_DIR}/${original/.m4a/.wav}"
    echo "${IN_FILE} => ${TMPFILE} => ${OUT_FILE}"
    (cd "${INPUT_DIR}" \
        && ffmpeg -i "${IN_FILE}" -y -f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 "${TMPFILE}" \
    )
    # ... do something with "${TMPFILE}", save as ${OUT_FILE}
    test -e "${TMPFILE}" && rm "${TMPFILE}"
done
```

When leaving the line with `ffmpeg`, some of the characters at the beginning of `${IN_FILE}` are missing, causing `ffmpeg` to fail (file not found). The characters are also missing in the output of the `echo` command.

However, when removing the `ffmpeg` line from the script, the output of the `echo` command looks fine.

Comment: Could you provide an example of 2 input arguments, and the associated echo line with the missing characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general way to separate the stream used for the loop from the stream used by the loop body, you can do the following :

```
while IFS= read -u 5 -r original
do
  # Loop body
done 5< <(cd "${INPUT_DIR}" && find . -type f -name '*.m4a')
```

This example uses file descriptor 5 (along with process substitution).  This is very useful, for instance, if you want to have a loop body that will perform `read` statements or other commands requiring user input, as failing to do that these commands would read from the same stream as the loop `read` statement, not from the terminal.

Preventing `ffmpeg` from accessing standard input, as suggested in a separate answer, is still a good idea, because while your loop stream is protected, there may still be something available on the standard input of the context which you would still want to protect from any attempt by `ffmpeg` to read.

Also, you may want to use null delimiters for file names, which allows handling of files with special characeters in their names (i.e. newlines).  You just need small changes to the `read` and `find` commands.

```
while IFS= read -d '' -u 5 -r original
do
  # Loop body
done 5< <(cd "${INPUT_DIR}" && find . -type f -name '*.m4a' -print0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this elucidating answer. It helped me a lot to understand the root cause of my problem.

Comment: It is, indeed, very useful, and it changed a lot of things for me when I found out about this myself.

Comment: Please note that you can nest a loop inside a loop, use the same file descriptor number for both, and they will not mix.  "5" is my personal standard (for no good reason), and I basically use it for every loop unless the loop is specifically supposed to be fed its input from standard input (i.e. for a "filtering" function).  This way, I avoid issues at the source (and these issues can be difficult to debug because they are not obvious).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this does not happen in the first iteration of the loop, it is likely that ffmpeg is consuming some of its stdin, and it is currently reading from the same stream as the while loop. Just close its input:

```
do
    TMPFILE="$(mktemp --dry-run)"
    IN_FILE="${INPUT_DIR}/${original}"
    OUT_FILE="${OUTPUT_DIR}/${original/.m4a/.wav}"
    echo "${IN_FILE} => ${TMPFILE} => ${OUT_FILE}"
    (cd "${INPUT_DIR}" \
        && ffmpeg <&1- -i "${IN_FILE}" -y -f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 "${TMPFILE}" \
    )
    # ... do something with "${TMPFILE}", save as ${OUT_FILE}
    test -e "${TMPFILE}" && rm "${TMPFILE}"
done
```

Comment: or `(cd ... && ffmpeg...) <<< ""` (but the explicit `<&1-` is much nicer. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your suggestion worked for me and in case there would be no other answer, I would have chosen this one as the most helpful one.